# delete/update/save doesnt work in datasource cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, datasource, cakephp-1.3

Im trying to use datasource plugin [CakePHP-Rest-Datasource](https://github.com/nodesagency/CakePHP-Rest-Datasource/blob/master/Model/Datasource/RestSource.php)

But the problem is the action. It always calls the read method. When i want to delete it doesn't call delete function, it calls only read and the same for update etc...

```
<?php
App::uses('Model', 'AppModel');

class Camping extends AppModel {
    public $useDbConfig = 'camping';
    public $remoteResource = 'api_camping';

    public $uses = false; // This model does not use a database table
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know this plugin, but I see one problem with your code... `$uses` specifies an array of models you want preloaded in a controller. If you want to set or disable a database table in the model, you should set `public $useTable = false;`

Comment: i did but the problem is that nothing special happens, for delete after 4 hours i found out that when i change delete with deleteAll() it works but really i don't know why this plugin doesnt recognize the delee function. otherwise have idea which rest plugin can i  use

Comment: Well I've never used an external source, so that's all I know here. Besides, now when I see it better, I don't think the `$useTable` variable is relevant, because you have set a different datasource. Hope you get it working. :)